# Sprite Kit animating score in increments

Tags: objective-c, animation, sprite-kit

So in my "game over" scene, I want to animate the score counting up like some games do. I have written a method like this:

```
-(void)animateScoreNumberLabel{
    if ([scoreNumberLabel.text integerValue]<SCORE) {
        [self runAction:[SKAction waitForDuration:.001f]completion:^{
            [self incrementScoreNumberLabel];
            [self animateScoreNumberLabel];
        }];
    }
}
```

And it works, but appears to "top off" at `.01f` waiting time - A.K.A., I can't get the animation to go any faster than 100 "increments" per second. With  a game where the average score ranges between 3000 and 10000, obviously I can't have people wating 30-100 seconds to see their full score.

Is there a better way to do this? I'm assuming maybe it has to do with the `if` statement?

**EDIT:** I tried this as well:

```
if ([scoreNumberLabel.text integerValue]<SCORE) {
        [self runAction:[SKAction runBlock:^{
            [self incrementScoreNumberLabel];
            [self animateScoreNumberLabel];
        }]];
    }
```

And it barely went faster - it's looking like I'll need to increment by more than 1 to do this, because it simply isn't fast enough. But then it gets a bit cumbersome to make sure that the incrementer doesn't go OVER the actual score... Bleh.

Comment: It looks like the update rate is limited by the frame rate (i.e, 60 fps). Perhaps you should increment by a larger amount (e.g., 10, 100) as the score increases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your users won't be able to perceive single digit increments at 60fps (the most common  refresh rate of display) and spriteKit appears to be locked to [the devices native refresh rate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKView/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKView/frameInterval) (which makes sense).

As you've pointed out there is opportunity for a large range in final scores and this could leave users waiting.

This problem was solved years ago, in arcade consoles. Try this:

1. Determine an acceptable length to tally your score…
2. Use a easing function to increment the score on `update:` method of your `SKScene`

You could probably use a basic ease-out function that starts out quickly and then slows down for the final few digits (of course you could use an ease-in i.e. get faster as you increment the total).

**NB.** This approach will also avoid the problem where a users device isn't matching the frame rate *you* expect.